# Separate items in ListView using line in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How to separate between items BY Lines in ListView control in WPF ?

Comment: Could you explain more, even if you can throw together an image of what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the ItemTemplate for the ListBox,
given the little information you have provided, just a quick example:

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding}/>
   </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You will have to modify it to suit your needs.